# Passing mongo aggregation to python

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I have the following piece of code in python which is trying to pass a `mongo` query. Details of the connection are below. When I execute this, I get "invalid syntax" and the syntax error points right after the code `"total:{"...` I think this has something to do with dictionary objects in Python but I am a little confused how to proceed.

```
import pymongo

from pymongo import MongoClient

client = MongoClient()

db = client.trackers

a = list((db.monthlytracker.aggregate([{$match:   
          {'Country':'Japan','Vendor':'Others'}}, 
          {$group:{_id:"$Fiscal Quarter",total:{$sum:"$Units"}}}])))
```

Answer (score 2):

You are using the wrong syntax. The pymongo driver accepts only strings:

```
a = list((db.monthlytracker.aggregate([{'$match':   
          {'Country':'Japan','Vendor':'Others'}}, 
          {'$group':{'_id':"$Fiscal Quarter",'total':{'$sum':"$Units"}}}])))
```

Simply quote everything, and you'll do fine.

The problem is that python looks to evaluate `$group` `$match` and so on, and it does not know about these variables. So you probably get errors like:

```
$match
  File "<ipython-input-1-972ca9ab5d06>", line 1
    $match
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

or:

```
NameError: name 'total' is not defined
```

and one more final thing, be careful with turning cursors to list objects, as you do with:

```
list(db.monthly.tracker.aggregate(...))
```

This can easily consume your memory. Instead you should iterate over the items in the cursor as with:

```
for item in db.monthly.tracker.aggregate(...):
    do_your_magic_here(item)
```

Comment: Thanks! Appreciate the quick response. So I tried quoting everything exactly as above but got a new error which said: KeyError: "['Units' 'MS Quarter'] not in index". I think this has more to do with the dictionary object  issue. For the original error, I didn't actually get a syntax error on match or the group function, it was when it hit "total" in the code. Thanks for the recommendation on the memory usage.

Comment: Correction: I think quoting match and group is necessary. The syntax error actually was pointing under $match to begin with...